# Should we set -Xmx (max java heap size) in a kubernetes container

Tags: java, kubernetes, heap-memory

### TLDR;

Why bother settings `-Xmx` and `-Xms` in a kubernetes app?

---

We've inherited a kubernetes app that is having out of memory errors.  It looks like the initial devs set kubernetes resource limits (.95 CPU core and 4Gb memory) as shown below.  However, they also set the max heap size in `JAVA_OPTS -Xmx` to 800mb.

[image]

I've found lots of good material on best settings for `-Xmx` (eg [this one](https://akobor.me/posts/heap-size-and-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-for-jvm-applications)), but can't find a straight answer to the following question: do we really need to set `-Xmx` (and less importantly, `-Xms`) in a kubernetes container?  We've already set hard limits on the container
`resources`, so what is the point to setting these flags?  If we removed them altogether, what would the consequence be?  Would the app GC more often?  Would it scale heap size dynamically or would heap size max be fixed at some default maxium like 256MB?  Is there any rule of thumb of setting `-Xmx` in proportion to kubernets containers?

Comment: FWIW I've deleted all of these in our code and running on relatively modern versions of k8s (as of writing I think it's 1.21 or 1.22) I haven't had to think about these flags..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set a maximum heap size the behavior depends on the java version used. Current JREs support determining the container limits and use that to guide their internal heuristics.

when running with an older version the memory to be used for the heap will be determined based on the physical memory visible to the container, which might be excessive.

Note that hitting the memory limit of the container will lead to killing the process and restarting the container.

I suggest you use a sane value, as determined from operational testing, for Xmx and Xms to get a stable memory usage.

Comment: (Note that "current JREs" includes ~2-year-old builds of old JREs like OpenJDK 8; if your base infrastructure is updated routinely then you should have support to automatically determine the heap size based on resource limits.)

Comment: Ok thanks!  I will check out our current JDK in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 10 and Java 8u191 there should be quite good support for Java determining actual memory available in the container. It's not necessary to use `-Xmx` anymore. It's recommended to use `XX:MaxRAMPercentage` with a value ranging between 75.0 and 80.0 (e.g. `XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0`)

Sources:
https://www.atamanroman.dev/development/2019/09/11/usecontainersupport-to-the-rescue.html
https://pretius.com/blog/jvm-kubernetes/

Comment: totally disagree: what is the point to have a dynamic heap size in a container environment? The memory is already compromised. IMHO, you should always set and use a XMS and XMX equals values for you container, since you have no benefit at all with the JVM resizing your heap memory.

Comment: No, it is not dynamic. This way you just don't need to specify memory limits twice, once for the container and once for the Java app. Otherwise, someone can keep increasing container memory and wonder why it doesn't help his app.
It is very cumbersome if you want to use a larger pod and you also need to fidle with this param in some completely different place.

Comment: You probably didn't understand the concept.

Comment: uhm, now I got why you are saying that. When you said that "someone can keep increasing container memory and wonder why it doesn't help his app", IMHO (again), this is typical example of a service that is not well designed to run on a container enviroment. For me, all services must be deployed and run with predictable resource management: if you need to deal with increase load, you should start new (stateless) instances, instead of increase you container memory usage. Ask for any SRE engineer, if they would approve an app that you have to monitor and increase  memory allocation on demand.

Comment: over here is a Devops / SRE Engineer which approves Ondrej's statements

Answer (score 0):

Use Xms and Xmx to set your heap min and max.  Do not use MaxRAMPercentage because when Java no longer works (as when Kubernetes moved to cgroups v2), the JVM will default to some values are incorrect and will lead to failures.

Source: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8230305